# What does "the mistrustful way he acts around Will" mean here?

Tags: meaning, literature

I am wondering what "the mistrustful way he acts around
Will" means in the following sentences:

> I watch Charlie until his gaze snags on mine – I make sure I’m the
> first to glance away. And I wonder: is he now the jealous one? I’ve
> seen **the mistrustful way he acts around Will**, as though he’s
> trying to find the flaw. I caught him observing the two of us over
> drinks. And I felt it again, how good we look together, imagining it
> through his eyes.

- Lucy Foley, *The Guest List*, Chapter 14

This is a thriller novel published in 2020 in the United Kingdom. One hundred and fifty guests would be gathering at some remote and deserted fictional islet called Inis an Amplóra off the coast of the island of Ireland to celebrate the wedding between Jules (a self-made woman running an online magazine called *The Download*) and Will (a celebrity appearing in a TV show program called *Survive the Night*). The day before the actual wedding day, during the rehearsal dinner, Jules sees Charlie. Jules once had a crush on Charlie when she was sixteen, and was secretly envious of Hannah for having married to Charlie, who once worked as a sailing instructor and is now working as a geography teacher for fifteen-year-old students. And she presently wonders whether Charlie is the jealous one now, because Jules is going to be married to Will. (The narrator here is Jules.)

In this part, I wonder what "the mistrustful way he acts around Will" means.

Would that mean Charlie's behaviour itself was mistrustful, like his behaviour contained many suspicious aspects?

Or, would that mean Charlie's behaviour towards Will revealed his mistrust towards Will, like Charlie does not believe Will is a good person...?

Comment: The latter interpretation is correct.

Comment: You can probably start to omit the paragraph starting "This is a thriller novel published in 2020" from now on. I think we all know what _The Guest List_ is by now.

Comment: Dear @MichaelHarvey, thank you very much for the comment. Then Charlie acted as if he didn't trust Will. I would omit the paragraph from the next question, as you suggest, unless more context is required. I sincerely appreciate your help. :)

Comment: For the first interpretation to apply, an appropriate word would be "untrustworthy", rather than "mistrustful". "Untrustworthy" means deserving mistrust, "mistrustful" means showing mistrust. Then there is the word "suspicious", which can mean either of those two things!

Comment: Dear @JamesMartin, thank you very much for the explanation! So "mistrustful" shows mistrust, whereas "untrustworthy" deserves mistrust. Indeed, "untrustworthy" would be more fitting to the first interpretation. I truly appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Charlie acts as if he _does not trust Will_. In the forest, I might act untrustfully around a hungry wolf, even if it has said it will not harm me.

Comment: 'Distrustful' also matches your first interpretation.

Comment: If the *behaviour was mistrustful*, that ***doesn't*** mean the behaviour *contained many suspicious aspects*. The writer is talking about ***Charlie** being "mistrustful" (he lacks trust / faith / confidence / belief)* - nothing to do with whether other people trust Charlie, or think he's acting in a way that arouses suspicion.

Comment: Dear @MichaelHarvey, mcalex and FumbleFingers, thank you very much for the explanations. So Charlie behaved like he didn't trust will, rather than behaving in a suspicious way! I truly appreciate your kindness in explaining this to me. :)

Comment: @JamesMartin Could that be posted as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I can understand why you question the meaning of this passage**

The question answers it's self when you retain the context.

Re-asking the question

> In this part, I wonder what *"I’ve seen the *mistrustful way he acts* around Will, as though he’s trying to find the flaw"*. means.

Then **the answer is obvious, but is it the correct one?** The one who is mistrustful is Charlie.

Charlie's behaviour itself was mistrustful, like his behaviour contained many suspicious aspects?

> **the *mistrustful way "he" acts*. The "He" being Charlie**

However if you look at the context of the passage this is **clearly not what the writer intended** to imply. Which I believe to be.

> Charlie's behaviour towards Will revealed his mistrust towards Will, like Charlie does not believe Will is a good person...?

Author's can also make mistakes, but the blame lies on the proof reader, that is what they are paid for!

---

proofreader: noun; a person whose job is to check text before it is printed or put online

> Grammarly’s online proofreader automatically detects grammar, spelling, punctuation, ***word choice and style mistakes*** in your writing.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment by James Martin:

> For the first interpretation to apply, an appropriate word would be "untrustworthy", rather than "mistrustful". "Untrustworthy" means deserving mistrust, "mistrustful" means showing mistrust. Then there is the word "suspicious", which can mean either of those two things!

Comment: It is better if you make this a community wiki answer

Comment: I meant to, but forgot to click the box at the last moment, and then didn't know whether I should bother the moderators by editing it for something so small.  I've done it now since you said it was a good idea.